# convert svg to css shape

Tags: css, svg, border

i am trying to do this "circle-Egg" in css and its not working with me.

i have this circle as an SVG , and i want to use it in my website and place an image inside it , 
using Pattern and Image to place image inside the svg was not working with me because i cant control background size and repeat .

```html
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="115" height="120"><defs><path id="a" d="M93.174 120C124.931 120 148 93.748 148 61.364S127.605 0 95.849 0C64.092 0 33 28.98 33 61.364S61.418 120 93.174 120z"/></defs><use fill="#00C1B1" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(-33)" xlink:href="#a"/></svg>
```

so i decided to make this picture using css

please note top left corner 
[Circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DOXp.png)

```css
.circle{
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-left:50px;
  background-color:#00C1B1;
  border-radius: 70% 50% 60% 60% / 70% 70% 55% 60%;
  height: 120px;
  width:115px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
</div>
```

i have tried to play around with border radius but it does not seems to work with me .

Thanks

Comment: share the SVG you have, we can use it for your image and without pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the SVG as mask and you can easily consider background. Simply make sure to correctly set the viewBox of the SVG:

```css
.box {
  -webkit-mask:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="30 0 120 120" ><path d="M93.174 120C124.931 120 148 93.748 148 61.364S127.605 0 95.849 0C64.092 0 33 28.98 33 61.364S61.418 120 93.174 120z" fill="black"/></svg>') center/contain no-repeat;
          mask:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="30 0 120 120" ><path d="M93.174 120C124.931 120 148 93.748 148 61.364S127.605 0 95.849 0C64.092 0 33 28.98 33 61.364S61.418 120 93.174 120z" fill="black"/></svg>') center/contain no-repeat;
   width:200px;
   display:inline-block;
   background:red;
}
/* to maintain the ratio */
.box::before {
   content:"";
   display:inline-block;
   padding-top:100%;
}


svg {
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box" style="background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1000/800/800.jpg) center/cover;width:150px;"></div>

<div class="box" style="background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1074/800/800.jpg) center/cover;width:100px"></div>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100" viewBox="30 0 120 120" ><path d="M93.174 120C124.931 120 148 93.748 148 61.364S127.605 0 95.849 0C64.092 0 33 28.98 33 61.364S61.418 120 93.174 120z" fill="black"/></svg>
```

Comment: @AhmadKhalaf I would say, I don't see whay it won't. In case you face any issue you can still come back here

Comment: i have updated the question , sadly after applying to React , the shape render but the image inside does not

Comment: @AhmadKhalaf please don't update your question with my answer. Your question need to remain as is it or it will make my answer irrelevant

Comment: @AhmadKhalaf you should either ask a new question or share the code outside the question so I can see. SO isn't a Chat system, we should have questsions and answers

Comment: @AhmadKhalaf also your screenshot are showing that the code is working fine since you can see the red background. The image is probably not loading, try a different one

Comment: sorry for the headache :) 
i tried another image , the result was the same , 

i will keep digging around it , thank a lot for your help

Comment: @AhmadKhalaf share your full code here: https://jsfiddle.net/ or share a live link of a website where you are trying

Comment: do u know if its possible to set a white border around the circle ? i can get an svg code for the border only if it will help

Comment: @AhmadKhalaf yes it's possible but I advice you to ask a new question to get help from the community ;) you may get many helpful answers